# TransformBack a Point with RotateTransform

Tags: .net, wpf

WPF has a `RotateTransform` class that can be applied to a `DrawingContext`. Any drawing operations performed with this transform in place will be rotated accordingly. I can call the `RotateTransform.Transform` method to explicitly rotate a single point in code. I use this transformation to freely rotate some diagram graphics.

Now, for proper mouse hit testing of the effective points, I need to reverse-rotate a given point with this `RotateTransform` instance. It doesn't seem to offer that though. How can this be done?

I'm looking for something like this `TransformBack` method, much like `IValueConverter` has a `Convert` and `ConvertBack` method:

```
var rotate = new RotateTransform(angle, centerX, centerY);
Point virtualPoint = new Point(100, 200);
Point realPoint = rotate.TransformBack(virtualPoint);   // Doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Inverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.inverse(v=vs.110).aspx) Transform:

```
var realPoint = rotate.Inverse.Transform(virtualPoint);
```